# Generate a dataset with only 6 decimal numbers

Tags: python, decimal

Is there a way to generate a (random) dataset that is filled with values having 6 decimals and 1 number before the decimal separator?

So for example like this:

```
 "A":[5.398811, 2.232098, 9.340909, 3.343434],
 "B":[6.436293,5.293756, 1.235937, 1.987384],
 "C": [3.572831, 3.826355, 3.827264, 3.257321]
```

I found that round(random.uniform(33.33, 66.66), 2) returns a random float number up to 2 decimal places. However, I don't want a dataframe filled "up to" 2 decimal places but a dataframe filled with only 6 decimal places. I would like to have about 1000 rows and 100 columns.

EDIT:
It would also be nice to not have any 0's or 9's in any of the decimals. This because I am looking into rounding decimals. When rounding 1.999999 to 5 decimals, one wil get 2.00000 which is 2. Which then will not give a reliable rounding result. Don't know to what extend that's actually feasible.

Comment: Obviously you start by changing the 2 by 6, and setting the minimum and maximum value to get 1 digit before the decimal point (hint: numbers should not be 10 or greater). Did you try that? What is then the problem?

Comment: use `round(random.uniform(0, 10), 6)`. Alternatively you can generate random 7 digit numbers and divide by million.

Comment: The problem for both these solutions is that there is a possibility of getting values with less than 6 decimals while I do need those 6 decimals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to generate numbers from 1,000,000 to 9,999,999 and then divide by 1,000,000. This will ensure that the numbers are always exactly 6 decimals.

Regarding the second condition, you can run a check on the number by casting to a string, something like:

```
if '9' in str(the_number): 
    continue
else:
    result.append(the_number)
```

Comment: what is 1M/1M in terms of decimal places? ;)

Comment: But how would I incorporate this in code of the answer above?

Comment: @mozway I completely forgot about zeroes in the first digit. Maybe add another check in the same if condition to check if `number%10 == 0` or maybe `len(str(number)) < 6`. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: converting to string is expensive, check my answer for another method ;)

Comment: @IrisJacobs the other answer provided a great solution. Don't bother with my answer.

Comment: @mozway It definitely is. But the second condition is pretty tough to check without converting to a string. And if we are going to convert it once, maybe do the rest of the operations on the string. Either way, your solution looks to be way cleaner and I would guess more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) for efficiency, then convert to dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
col,row = (10,20)  # (100, 1000) in your case
out = dict(enumerate(np.random.uniform(0,10,size=col*row)
                       .round(6).reshape(row,col).tolist()))

print(out)
```

output:

```
{0: [5.488135, 7.151894, 6.027634, 5.448832, 4.236548, 6.458941, 4.375872, 8.91773, 9.636628, 3.834415],
 1: [7.91725, 5.288949, 5.680446, 9.255966, 0.710361, 0.871293, 0.202184, 8.326198, 7.781568, 8.700121],
 2: [9.786183, 7.991586, 4.614794, 7.805292, 1.182744, 6.39921, 1.433533, 9.446689, 5.218483, 4.146619],
...
 19: [3.982211, 2.098437, 1.86193, 9.443724, 7.395508, 4.904588, 2.274146, 2.543565, 0.580292, 4.344166],
}
```

*NB. note that the numbers will be **UP TO** 6 decimal digits (e.g., 0.123400 will be shown as 0.1234, forcing otherwise would create a non-random bias*

pure python version (less efficient):

```
import random
out = {i: [round(random.uniform(0, 10), 6) for j in range(100)]
       for i in range(1000)}
```

##### exactly 6 digits

You can check if the rounded number has a zero on the 6th decimal place, and in this case add an arbitrary number.
Here is an example, initial dataset:

```
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility
a = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=20).round(6)

array([5.488135, 7.151894, 6.027634, 5.448832, 4.236548, 6.458941,
       4.375872, 8.91773 , 9.636628, 3.834415, 7.91725 , 5.288949,
       5.680446, 9.255966, 0.710361, 0.871293, 0.202184, 8.326198,
       7.781568, 8.700121])
```

With correction:

```
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility
a = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=20).round(6)
# identify numbers ending in 0
mask = (a*1e6).astype(int)%10==0
# add a terminal 1
a[mask] += 1e-6
a

array([5.488135, 7.151894, 6.027634, 5.448832, 4.236548, 6.458941,
       4.375872, 8.917731, 9.636628, 3.834415, 7.917251, 5.288949,
       5.680446, 9.255966, 0.710361, 0.871293, 0.202184, 8.326198,
       7.781568, 8.700121])
```

This works by multiplying by 1e6 as integer and getting the remainder of division by 10:

```
(a*1e6).astype(int)%10

array([5, 4, 4, 2, 8, 1, 2, 0, 8, 5, 0, 9, 6, 6, 1, 3, 4, 8, 8, 1])
```

##### example with DataFrame

```
import numpy as np
col,row = (4,5)  # (100, 1000) in your case
a = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=col*row).round(6).reshape(row,col)
mask = (a*1e6+1).astype(int)%10<2
# add a terminal 1
a[mask] += 2e-6

df = pd.DataFrame(a)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3
0  5.488135  7.151894  6.027634  5.448832
1  4.236548  6.458941  4.375872  8.917732
2  9.636628  3.834415  7.917252  5.288951
3  5.680446  9.255966  0.710361  0.871293
4  0.202184  8.326198  7.781568  8.700121
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution already, I would not mind a non-random bias, I just need a 6 decimal filled dataframe

Comment: @Iris may I ask what is the use case?

Comment: Yes, I want to assess results of rounding values in a dataset on its CSV file storage. I want these results to be fully reliable. However, I realized that when rounding a 1.999 to 2 decimal places it will result in a 2.000 which is a 2. Therefore it would be nice to also not have any 9's in the numbers.

Comment: I provided an update

Comment: Hi yes thank you, I don't want to be difficult because I am very thankful for your solution and effort already but is it possible to also remove any 9's and 0's from the numbers, that way the measure for rounding will be fully reliable as no digits will disappear when rounding...

Comment: Sure, you can change the condition. Instead of `n%10==0` use `(n+1)%10<2`

Comment: Okay I'm still doing something wrong, I have this now: import random
out = {i: [round(random.uniform(1, 9.999999), 6) for j in range(100)]
       for i in range(1000)}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(out)

mask = (df*1e6).astype(int)+1%10<2
df[mask] += 1e-6
and it still returns 9's and 0's in the decimals

Comment: The mask is for the numpy solution ;)

Comment: Ow oops, how do I do this for a dataframe?

Comment: See update for a DataFrame

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I think I was not clear, I want no 0's nor 9's in all my decimals. So not even 1.984375 or 1.700534

Comment: Hmmm, then that's quite different from the initial question. You might need to use strings or base 9? I'll pass for today, good luck ;)

Comment: I think I'll just leave it at that, it's a large enough dataframe to get reliable results. Thankyou so much for your help!