# Replace decimals in floating point numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, decimal

Someone on this platform has already [helped me with generating the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72396148/16343464):

```
col,row = (100,1000) 
a = np.random.uniform(0,10,size=col*row).round(6).reshape(row,col)
mask = (a*1e6+1).astype(int)%10<2
a[mask] += 2e-6
```

This code ensures that the last decimal is not a 0 or a 9. However, I would like to have no 0's nor 9's in all the decimals that are generated (such that it will not be possible to have a number 1.963749 or 3.459007).

It would be fine for all 0's and 9's to be, for example, replaced by a 2 (1.263742 and 3.452227 considering the example above). I know that the function replace (0, 2) does not work for the decimal numbers. Is there a way to replace these numbers or should the code be rewritten to make this work?

Comment: Convert the number to a string, replace all the 0 and 9, then parse it back to a float.

Comment: This does not seem to work for a whole dataframe

Comment: This seems to be a very strange requirement. What's the use case?

Comment: Does the bias in that solution not bother you?

Comment: No it does not, I can imagine this to be very strange. I am looking into the effect of rounding on storage space. 0's and 9's can result in trailing zero's which can skew results :)

Comment: Is this about adjusting numbers you already have, or is this about *generating* random numbers with the desired property? In the latter case I'd have another solution...

Comment: @Kelly no, I already pointed the bias in the previous question and this was not a problem, as weird as it can seem to be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using strings (I find it non-elegant but it works).

Assuming this input as pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
       col1      col2
0  1.234567  9.999909
1  1.999999  0.120949
```

You can stack and replace as string:

```
def rand(x):
    import random
    return random.choice(list('12345678'))

df2 = (df
 .stack()
 .astype(str)
 .str.replace(r'[09](?!.*\.)', rand)
 .astype(float)
 .unstack()
 )
```

Output:

```
       col1      col2
0  1.234567  9.665236
1  1.184731  0.128345
```

Comment: Thankyou! this work! Is it also possible to replace the 0's and 9's before the decimal separator by regex?

Comment: Yes, just use `r'[09]'` as regex

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that generates each digit position separately ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LczBCsIwEATQe75ijkmIJUUQPPgxQaMGzO6SppR@fdyKc9iBhTey9zfTeYxShVsHrVV2pAUkxtz5ExpvuMHOMQboic6YpI9lrZZkaokeXH9VqNs54Bpg1QQodg5ekffZ4J8nN2QUgpJXtqeLrjrdlHb45Mb4Ag)):

```
a = sum(np.random.randint(1, 9, (row, col)) * 10**e
        for e in range(-6, 1))
```

With more NumPy ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCgIhFEX3fsVd@sREC4oWfckwC6mogXyK4xDz9fZscy9czrllb@/Mp96XVHJt4C2VHXEFF6Xu@WNr/uIGHby3kPCkVBwDF1cjP3L618JNB4urhRbBYpi4EMFgmoJ3xggfhXw99eEsTzTP5NYt6aMcljr8SL3/AA)):

```
a = (np.random.randint(1, 9, (row, col, 7)) * [[10.**np.arange(-6, 1)]]).sum(2)
```